# R, in function using if else statements, keep getting Error in if (x[2] == "h") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement

I have data similar to the below in  a df. I wrote a function to convert it to time in minutes.

```
90 min
39 min
21 min
109 min
100 min
97 min
110 min
84 min
97 min
94 min
80 min
110 min
30 min
95 min
59 min
9 min
2 h 5 min
3 h 45 min
4h
N/A
NA
78 min
80 min
108 min
85 min
5 min
83 min
```

I wrote this function and keep getting the error missing value where True/False needed. I think I've taken care of the NA and N/A cases, but still get the error. What do I need to do to correct the function and eliminate the error?

```
myfunction <- function(x){

  if (x=="N/A"){
    x <- NA
  } else if(is.na(x)){
    x <- NA
  }

  x <- unlist(strsplit(x, " ", fixed=TRUE))

  if(x[2]=='min'){
    x <- as.numeric((x[1]))
  }
  if(!is.na(x)){
    if (x[2]=='h'){
      if (is.null(x[4])||is.na(x[4])){
        x <- (as.numeric((x[1])))*60
      }
      if (x[4]=='min')  {
        x <- (as.numeric((x[1])))*60 + as.numeric((x[3]))
      } 
    }
  }

  return(x)}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve.  This code could almost certainly be vectorized and made a lot cleaner.

Comment: Your first check, `if (!is.na(x))` will only check the first value of x for missing values. If you only want to proceed if there are no missing values, you should instead use `if (!any(is.na(x)))`.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, but that still gives the same error. Time, I want to convert it to minutes, but without the "min". I do have an alternative function, but I would like to get this working.